# Why is the integral expression for the length of a curve more complicated than the expression for area or volume of a figure rotated?

Tags: calculus

There are quite simple, intuitive and straightforward expressions for evaluating the area or volume of a figure. But why is the expression for the length of a curve so complicated?

Comment: In what sense is it more complicated?  Is it because of the appearance of the square root which makes it hard to find an anti-derivative, even though the function may have a nice anti-derivative?

Comment: Yes; the square root makes things more complicated. Moreover in the other cases, it is a differential form of a certain weight.

Comment: In all cases you're integrating a differential form.  The cases are really not different since in each one you integrate the volume element over a manifold (a 1-manifold in the case of finding the length of the curve).  The difference is that in finding the length of the curve, the volume element is induced by the metric.

Answer (score 5):

The length of a curve doesn't transform in a nice way under scaling of one of the variables the same way that the area of a 2d figure or the volume of a 3d figure does.  That puts a hard lower bound on how complicated it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this depends on the shape, as you implied. I would say for a circle the circumference formula is simpler.

Also the length of the curve **is a volume** in some sense, its just 1 dimensional.

Usually in calculus we are calculating the area relative to the the x-axis, and your formula is in terms of $x$, so that makes things simpler. I imagine that if the curve was parameterized in terms of its arc length finding its length would be quite trivial, and finding the area between the curve and the x-axis would seem very complicated.